# How do I print the first letter of a word?

Tags: python

I looked through other problems and they don't seem to be helpful for me, so I decided to ask.

My code has created a random variable from my file (NECESSARY)
I want to print the string that comes with my variable, but I only want it to print the first letter of the string.

E.G. It is a song name like "Cheese", I only want "C?????" to be printed but I am not sure how to tackle this problem as I am a new coder.

I have tried to have the word in the string alone, as before hand it has the Artist name with it but I removed it so it is just 1 word as it can be split easier for a beginner.

```
import random

EFile=open("ExternalFile.txt","w+")

Info1=("Shotgun")
Info2=("God's Plan")
Info3=("This is me")
Info4=("Solo")
Info5=("Psyco")

EFile.write(Info1)
EFile.write(Info2)
EFile.write(Info3)
EFile.write(Info4)
EFile.write(Info5)
EFile.close

Array=[Info1, Info2, Info3, Info4, Info5]

RanVar=random.choice(Array)
print(RanVar)
```

This part of the code works well, and it chooses one of the variables at random, but I need the strings attacked to the variables 'Info' to only print the first letter, and if possible, print the rest of the words as question marks.

If that is too complex for a beginner, I would like it to just be the first letter.

Comment: Use `string[i]` to access the character of `string` at index `i`. Also see [slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/).

Comment: Not sure to get your question, but if you want to print the string you can do it this way : `print(myvar[0]+'?'*(len(myvar)-1))`

Comment: I am l literally brand new to coding so this is immensely confusing to me sometimes.

Comment: I just want to print the first letter of the string, so it only shows E.G. S from Shotgun

Answer (score 2):

You can just write the first letter using `RanVar[0]` and then the rest by writing "?" 1 less time than the total length of `RanVar` using the code `'?'*(len(RanVar)-1)`. Then you just concatenate these together with `+`

```
import random
Info1=("Shotgun")
Info2=("God's Plan")
Info3=("This is me")
Info4=("Solo")
Info5=("Psyco")

Array=[Info1, Info2, Info3, Info4, Info5]

RanVar=random.choice(Array)
print(RanVar[0]+'?'*(len(RanVar)-1))
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't print the amount of question marks equivalent to the amount of characters in the string. Any idea?

Comment: @LordDoe Are you sure? [it worked for me](https://repl.it/@JamieCohen/SplendidUnselfishApache)

Comment: It's just that "Shotgun" and "Solo" have the same 1st letter: S.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1# using for loop

```
content=["Shotgun","God's Plan","This is me","Solo","Psyco"]
chars=[]
for y in content:
    chars.append(y[0])
print(chars)
```

Approach 2# list comprehension

```
content=["Shotgun","God's Plan","This is me","Solo","Psyco"]
chars=[y[0] for y in content ]
print(chars)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python treats every string as an array. you can print the letters with their index. The code below can be even simpler (I made it easy to select which letter to print)

```
import random

EFile=open("ExternalFile.txt","w+")
Info = ["Shotgun","God's Plan","This is me","Solo","Psyco"]
for w in Info:
    EFile.write(w)
EFile.close

RanVar=random.choice(Info)

for i, letter in enumerate(RanVar):
    if i == 0:
        print (letter, end ="")
    else:
        print ('?', end ="")

print ('\n')
```

Comment: I disagree with the fact you specify end="" at the end of the word, if this is a guess game, the op will probably need to print things after that ^^

Comment: Changed as requested (although I think it's obvious enough?)

Comment: We never know ! :p